# How do I embed a web form (with iframe) onto one of my clients web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like to take a web form like https://www.elbowspace.com/FRHformexample142
and embed the html in an iframe on my clients web site. The reason is I would like to retain my clients URL in the address box, while utilizing the look and backend processing of elbowspace.com. This form uses a lot of JavaScript for calcs that I don't want disrupted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to embed their form into your webpage like this. 
`<iframe src="https://www.elbowspace.com/FRHformexample142" height="2000px" width="1000px"></iframe>`.  All you need to do is change the height and width of the iframe to fix your needs.

Comment: I thought it would be way more complicated, thanks. Are there any disadvantages to using iframe like google page rank?

Comment: I am unsure how this affects anything like Google page rank. I do not think this will affect it because that is determined by SEO.